# Error "namespace cv::aruco has no member :CharucoBoard"

Tags: c++, opencv, aruco

I am trying to calibrate cameras using the ChArUcoBoard (chessboard + ArUco) class in C++, but getting the following error while importing the Charuco class: ""namespace cv::aruco has no member :CharucoBoard". In fact, I am unable to import any of the "Charuco" related functionalities. I have compiled the Opencv3.3.0 libraries and am able to use the entire "aruco" class except the "Charuco" functions. Could you please point me to what could have possible gone wrong there?

Comment: did you install the aruco using the repo contrib master?

Comment: Yes, I used opencv-contrib. I am using a Win 10 machine and running my codes using VS 2017.

Comment: then in the src folder is the charuco.cpp file...

Comment: Yes, it is there.

Comment: I see a "charuco.hpp" in the compiled folder "C:\aruco\opencv3\install\include\opencv2\aruco. I included that to my routine as "#include "opencv2\aruco\charuco.hpp" and it seems to have solved the problem. I am relatively new to C++, could you please help me understand why did it work?

Comment: post the code how are you using the charuco

Comment: Sorry for a late reply, but it worked by including "charuco.hpp".